# Can a script that is run as root, run another script as normal user?

Tags: scripts

So, if I run script as root using `gksu`, can that script run another script as normal user? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is basically what sudo does. You can run a command as another user by typing:

```
sudo -u [user] <command>
```

or

```
sudo --user=[user] <command>
```

The sudo command is very flexible, and you can find out the many options you have with it using the man pages or the help option:

```
sudo --help
man sudo
```